# Determine conditions on parameters (for consistency) on RK method $y_{n+1} = y_n + ha_1f(t_n,y_n) + ha_2f(t_n + b_1h, y_n + b_2hf(t_n,y_n))$

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, runge-kutta-methods

I'm asked to find the conditions on the coefficients $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ in the RK method
$$y_{n+1} = y_n + ha_1f(t_n,y_n) + ha_2f(t_n + b_1h, y_n + b_2hf(t_n,y_n))$$
such that is consistent of **(a)** first order and **(b)** second order.

The first assumption I make is that $b_1 = b_2 := b$ otherwise I have no idea how to solve it. I know it should be like this, but why is this reasonable? I know it follows if you look at the butcher tablaeu, but why is a method with $b_1 \neq b_2$ "impossible"?

I taylor expand $y(t_{n+1})$,
$$y(t_{n+1}) = y(t_n) + hy'(t_n) + O(h^2).$$
The order of consistency is $p$ if $l = O(h^{p+1})$ where $l$ is the local residual.

The local residual takes the form
$$y(t_n) + hy'(t_n) + O(h^2) - y(t_n) - ha_1f(t_n,y_n) - ha_2f(t_{n+b}, y_{n+b}) $$
$$= hy'(t_n) - ha_1y'(t_n) - ha_2y'(t_{n+b}) + O(h^2).$$
So I need to find $a_1,a_2,b$ so that every term except the $O(h^2)$ remains. I get for **(a)** 
$$a_1 + a_2 = 1, b=0.$$

For **(b)** I expand one term more 
$$y(t_{n+1}) = y(t_n) + hy'(t_n) + \frac{h^2y''(t_n)}{2} + O(h^3)$$
The local residual becomes 
$$y(t_n) + hy'(t_n) + \frac{h^2y''(t_n)}{2} + O(h^3) - y(t_n) - ha_1y(t_n) - ha_2y(t_{n+b}) $$

But here I am stuck. How am I supposed to choose the coefficients as to remove the $\frac{h^2y''(t_n)}{2}$ term?

How do I solve (b)? And is my answer on (a) correct?

Comment: Please indicate cross posts of the same problem: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/30721/6839

Comment: Related with partial solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2715967/runge-kutta-order-of-accuracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the method to $f(t,x)=1$, $f(t,x)=2t$ and $f(t,x)=x$ at $(t_0,x_0)=(0,1)$ to get
\begin{align}
f(t,x)=1&:& 1+h &= 1+ha_1+ha_2         &\implies& a_1+a_2=1\\
f(t,x)=2t&:& 1+h^2 &= 1+ha_2(2(b_1h))  &\implies& 2a_2b_1=1\\
f(t,x)=x&:& e^h &= 1+ha_1+ha_2(1+b_2h)) + O(h^3)&\implies& a_2b_2=\frac12
\end{align}
so one gets necessarily $a_1=1-a_2$ and $b_1=b_2=\frac1{2a_2}$. Now insert these conditions into the Taylor expansion to find that they are also sufficient for all continuously differentiable $f$.